# Start a jar on a raspberry pi by reboot

Tags: java, cron, raspberry-pi, autostart

i search a way to start a jar on a raspberry pi. In need to start the jar as root because the jar set gpios and this is only possible as root user.

The jar is a GUI fullscreen application. This i tried already:

- Create a Crontab (contab -e, @reboot, don't work because the application is a gui application)
- By adding a file called /etc/xdg/autostart/RPi-infoscreen.desktop

  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Name=RPi-infoscreen
  Comment=Keysystem
  NoDisplay=false
  Exec=/usr/bin/lxterminal -e /home/pi/keySys.sh
  NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;XFCE;

The command line program is at /home/pi/keySys.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Key
sudo java -jar keyTest.jar
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/keySys.sh
```

This had worked for me first. But than i had to change it because i need to see the exception from the terminal. So i changed the command line program what is at /home/pi/keySys.sh to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Key
sudo java -jar keyTest.jar 2> errorOutput.log > output.log &
```

Since this time nothing worked anymore. I changed it back to sudo java -jar keyTest.jar but it don't start the application anymore. I make it executable again but nothing happened.

Have someone a idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered to split the application into two jars. One jar containing the program logic (runs with root privileges) and the other containing the GUI (runs with user privileges). Then you could use SystemD to start the logic part. (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Runs the application in two jars is no option for me. I have no idea how the applications have to communicate to each other... There must be a way to start a application as root or not?

Comment: Had changed the keySys.sh to:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Key
sudo java -jar keyTest.jar 2>> log.txt, now it work!